# My New Internal HD is mounted as /Volumes/hdd

Tags: macbook-pro, partition, disk-volume

I replaced my optical disk with an SSD for startup and Mountain Lion and upgraded my HDD to a larger one.

I also moved my home folder to the new disk.  But one thing is still bugging me.

My mid-2010 MBP automatically mounts the new drive as /Volumes/hdd.  Do I need /Volumes in there?  Do I have to do a symlink?

Maybe this is weird, but I'd like the new drive to behave like the startup drive but not actually *be* the start up drive.

Comment: So your home folder is now inside `/Volumes/hdd`, but you would like it located as usual in `/Users/<your username>`, is that right? Do you have any other data on your new HDD? Can you please open Terminal (Applications>Utilities), type `df` and add it to your question?